# Angular async validators making multiple http calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, asyncvalidators

I have a custom async validator in Angular app that validates the uniqueness of a value. The validator makes HTTP calls to the backend API. I am trying to control the number of API calls by adding `distinctUntilChanged` and `debounceTime`, but that doesn't seem to be working fine. It is making call for everykey stroke.

Where am I going  wrong?

I tried using valueChanges of the control and things work fine, but I have a use case where I need to run all validators to check for error by clicking a single button on the form, is there a way to run all validators on the form irrespective of value changes?

With my current approach I am able to run all validations by clicking a single button, but it doesn't obey RxJS operators.

```
function uniqueAltIdValue(type, productId): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        const value: string = control.value;

        return validateValue(type, value).pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            debounceTime(800),
            map((response: { id: string; isValid: boolean }) =>
                (productId.toLowerCase() !== response.id.toLowerCase() && !response.isValid)
                    ? { valueExists: true }
                    : null,
            ),

            catchError(() => of({ valueExists: true })),
        );
    };
}

function validateValue(type: string, value: string): Observable<{ id: string; isValid: boolean }> {
    return this._httpService.requestCall(`${this.url}?type=${type}&id=${value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returned from `uniqueAltIdValue()` is called every time the form runs validators so in your case you're creating a separate chain each time. In turn, this means that each time a validator is executed you're creating a new Observable and that's why `distinctUntilChanged()` or `debounceTime()` have no effect in your case.

What you can do instead is returning a `Subject` and then pushing values into it when you need to run validation. You also want to call `validateValue()` after `deboucneTime()` and `distinctUntilChanged()`.

```
function uniqueAltIdValue(type, productId): AsyncValidatorFn {
    const subject = new Subject();
    const validate$ = subject.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        debounceTime(800),
        switchMap(() => validateValue(type, value)),
        map((response: { id: string; isValid: boolean }) =>
                (productId.toLowerCase() !== response.id.toLowerCase() && !response.isValid)
                    ? { valueExists: true }
                    : null,
        ),
        catchError(() => of({ valueExists: true })),
    )

    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        subject.next(control.value);
        return validate$;
    };
}
```

Note, that I didn't test the code, but I'm sure you'll get the point.

I'm suspicious that `distinctUntilChanged()` maybe even shouldn't be there because Angular's forms might wait until all validators emit and if `distinctUntilChanged()` ignores values it might break validation (but I'm not completely sure about this so maybe it's fine).